# Can't format pendrive whatever I do

Tags: formatting, efi, disk-utility, diskpart, disk-operating-system

I really need help. Even if you are not sure of the solution, please suggest something. I really need it.

I formatted a pendrive in macOS using disk utility (GUID, macOS extended journaled). Then I copied macOS setup for hackintosh. Then I used clover(software to make macOS pendrive bootable) to mount the efi partition. It created a 200MB efi partition. Later I needed to format the drive to use it. On windows, disk management doesn't show the option to delete the efi partition. It shows option to delete the larger partition but even after clicking delete nothing happens. I read many articles on internet. I used diskpart as administrator and selected my disk and used `clean` command. It showed disk cleaned successfully but it lied. The disk is the same. With efi partition and the data on the main partition also there. I first tried macOS disk utility to erase the disk but it says failed to erase the disk. Under details, it says partition not unmounted. I booted into my linux, used terminal `df` to list disks. Then unmounted the pendrive using `umount`.
Then formatted using `mkfs`. All commands are sudo. Terminal showed cleaning disk, creating partition table etc. After it was over, I see again that the disk is unaffected. It's new pendrive. Worked fine. No problems with pendrive whatsoever.

I also tried third party softwares but they all do what diskpart in Windows and terminal in Linux did which is => showed formatting completed but actually nothing happened to the pendrive. Please help me format it.

Comment: The stick might be broken.

Comment: I don't think so. It shows all the content on it. I think the mounting by clover is causing the problem. It worked absolutely fine. Now too. It's detected. Show contents. Can use contents. Just can't format it. MacOS disk utility says can't format mounted disk. But after I unmount it then it disappears from the list so how can erase it then. That's the problem.

Comment: Check if it hasn't become read-only.

Comment: How to check that.  I have all OS. macOS. Linux. Windows.

Comment: Try on Windows [this procedure](https://www.diskpart.com/articles/remove-write-protection-from-usb-1203.html).